# Battleship Model - follow-up

Tags: c#, beginner, game, battleship

This is the revised code from my [prior question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/204895/battleship-model). Same requests as before! Something I'm doing new here is using the `XmlEncoder` extension methods to handle serialization and de-serialization.

**XmlEncoder.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Battleship
{
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347642/deserialize-from-string-instead-textreader#2347661
    public static class XmlEncoder
    {
        public static string XmlSerializeToString(this object objectInstance)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectInstance.GetType());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, objectInstance);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public static T XmlDeserializeFromString<T>(this string objectData)
        {
            return (T)XmlDeserializeFromString(objectData, typeof(T));
        }

        public static object XmlDeserializeFromString(this string objectData, Type type)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
            object result;

            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(objectData))
            {
                result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**GridSquare.cs**

```
namespace Battleship
{
    public enum SquareType
    {
        Foggy,
        Water,
        Undamaged,
        Damaged,
        Sunk
    }

    public class GridSquare
    {
        public SquareType Type { get; set; }
        public int ShipIndex { get; set; }

        public GridSquare()
        {
            Type = SquareType.Foggy;
            ShipIndex = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

**Grid.cs**

```
namespace Battleship
{
    public class Grid
    {
        public GridSquare[,] Squares { get; private set; }
        public int Size { get; private set; }

        public Grid(int gridSize)
        {
            Size = gridSize;
            Squares = new GridSquare[gridSize, gridSize];

            for (int x = 0; x < gridSize; ++x)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < gridSize; ++y)
                {
                    Squares[x, y] = new GridSquare();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Ship.cs**

```
namespace Battleship
{
    // the classic rules (patrol boats aren't fit for warfare)
    public enum ShipType
    {
        Carrier = 5,
        Battleship = 4,
        Cruiser = 3,
        Submarine = 3,
        Destroyer = 2
    }

    public enum Orientation
    {
        South = 0,
        East = 1,
        North = 2,
        West = 3
    }

    internal static class OrientationExtension
    {
        public static Orientation GetOrientation(this int n)
        {
            switch (n)
            {
                case 1:
                    return Orientation.East;
                case 2:
                    return Orientation.North;
                case 3:
                    return Orientation.West;
                default:
                    return Orientation.South;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Ship
    {
        public ShipType ShipType { get; set; }
        public Orientation Orientation { get; set; }
        public int Health { get; set; }

        public Ship()
        {
            ShipType = ShipType.Destroyer;
            Repair();
        }

        public int GetLength()
        {
            return (int)ShipType;
        }

        public void Repair()
        {
            Health = GetLength();
        }

        public bool Sunk()
        {
            return Health == 0;
        }

        public void Hit()
        {
            if (Health > 0)
            {
                --Health;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Player.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Battleship
{
    public class Player
    {
        public Grid Grid { get; set; }
        public List<Ship> Ships { get; set; }

        protected static Random rand = new Random();

        public Player(int gridSize)
        {
            Grid = new Grid(gridSize);
            Ships = new List<Ship>();

            foreach (ShipType type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ShipType)))
            {
                Ships.Add(new Ship
                {
                    ShipType = type
                });
            }

            PlaceShips();
        }

        private void PlaceShips()
        {
            for (int shipIndex = 0; shipIndex < Ships.Count; ++shipIndex)
            {
                int x = rand.Next(Grid.Size);
                int y = rand.Next(Grid.Size);
                GridSquare sea = Grid.Squares[x, y];
                Ship ship = Ships[shipIndex];
                List<Orientation> validOrientations = new List<Orientation>();

                // calculate valid orientations
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
                {
                    Orientation o = i.GetOrientation();
                    bool done = false;

                    try
                    {
                        for (int j = 1; j < ship.GetLength() && !done; ++j)
                        {
                            switch (o)
                            {
                                case Orientation.South:
                                    if (Grid.Squares[x, y - j].ShipIndex != -1)
                                    {
                                        done = true;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case Orientation.East:
                                    if (Grid.Squares[x - j, y].ShipIndex != -1)
                                    {
                                        done = true;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case Orientation.North:
                                    if (Grid.Squares[x, y + j].ShipIndex != -1)
                                    {
                                        done = true;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case Orientation.West:
                                    if (Grid.Squares[x + j, y].ShipIndex != -1)
                                    {
                                        done = true;
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }

                            if (j == Grid.Size - 1)
                            {
                                validOrientations.Add(o);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception err)
                    {
                        if (err is IndexOutOfRangeException)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ship.ShipType + " fell off the edge of the world while heading " + o + "!");
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!validOrientations.Any())
                {
                    throw new Exception("The current grid cannot fit all of the ships!");
                }

                // set the origin metadata
                sea.Type = SquareType.Undamaged;
                sea.ShipIndex = shipIndex;
                ship.Orientation = validOrientations[rand.Next(validOrientations.Count)];

                // pick an orientation at random and layout the ship
                for (int i = 1; i < ship.GetLength(); ++i)
                {
                    switch (ship.Orientation)
                    {
                        case Orientation.South:
                            Grid.Squares[x, y - i].ShipIndex = shipIndex;
                            break;
                        case Orientation.East:
                            Grid.Squares[x - i, y].ShipIndex = shipIndex;
                            break;
                        case Orientation.North:
                            Grid.Squares[x, y + i].ShipIndex = shipIndex;
                            break;
                        case Orientation.West:
                            Grid.Squares[x + i, y].ShipIndex = shipIndex;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Attack(int x, int y)
        {
            GridSquare sea = Grid.Squares[x, y];

            switch (sea.Type)
            {
                case SquareType.Foggy: // miss
                    sea.Type = SquareType.Water;
                    break;
                case SquareType.Undamaged:
                    Ship ship = Ships[sea.ShipIndex];

                    ship.Hit();

                    if (ship.Sunk())
                    {
                        sea.Type = SquareType.Sunk;

                        for (int i = 1; i < ship.GetLength(); ++i)
                        {
                            switch (ship.Orientation)
                            {
                                case Orientation.South:
                                    Grid.Squares[x, y - i].Type = SquareType.Sunk;
                                    break;
                                case Orientation.East:
                                    Grid.Squares[x - i, y].Type = SquareType.Sunk;
                                    break;
                                case Orientation.North:
                                    Grid.Squares[x, y + i].Type = SquareType.Sunk;
                                    break;
                                case Orientation.West:
                                    Grid.Squares[x + i, y].Type = SquareType.Sunk;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sea.Type = SquareType.Damaged;
                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("You cannot change that square type!");
            }
        }

        public bool GameOver()
        {
            return Ships.All(ship => ship.Sunk());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to study [this implementation](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Battleship). It's VBA, but it's full-blown OOP (MVC) and you'll find that the model classes' (`AIPlayer`, `PlayerGrid`, `Ship`) responsilities are very clear-cut - GridSize has no business in a Player class, for example, and then the strategy an AI player uses to place its ships or pick an attack position can be abstracted and injected, too.

Comment: Looks good! I reverted my prior change to adhere to OOP standards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Inconsistent use of `var`

I love `var`, I use it pretty much everywhere. IMO *not* using it makes C# read like Java, and that can't be good. But that's just my opinion, and given a code base that doesn't use it, I'll conform to the style in place and keep its [non-]usage consistent - because whether you choose to use it or not, what matters is *consistency*. With that in mind, this is rather disturbing:

```
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectInstance.GetType());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

Syntactically, the two statements are essentially the same. Yet one uses `var`, and the other doesn't, for no apparent reason. Since that's the only place `var` is used, I'd change `var serializer` to `XmlSerializer serializer` and move on.

#### ++thing | thing++

Seeing `++i` is disturbing. It makes you stop and think "wait what's the reason for pre-[in|de]crementing here?", for no reason at all, because there's no reason at all to do `++i` in a `for` loop, besides coding style perhaps (makes no difference because the increment's returned value isn't used anyway). That's why some will see it as a subjective nitpick, but IMO if typing `for` and hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> in Visual Studio makes a default auto-template that does `i++`, then it's reasonable to consider `i++` in a `for` loop as the least surprising "style"... now that said you're consistent about using *prefix* in situations that make no difference, so I'll give you that. But I would have no difficulty believing *postfix* is the prevalent and expected "style".

If you're using `++i` because of some misguided micro-performance optimization concern, I encourage you to read [Eric Lippert's excellent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3346729/1188513) describing how prefix and postfix works.

---

> ```
> public static Orientation GetOrientation(this int n)
> ```

I don't think this is a good extension method to have. Especially since `Orientation` is an enum, which *already* readily casts to/from `int`... and I would expect the `default` case to throw, not return some arbitrary value. But `switch` is typically seen switching on enums, not on integers. It's ...weird, and likely not needed at all.

The name is wrong, too. `ToOrientation` would be more appropriate. "Get" sounds like you're *fetching* something; "To" is commonly used to convey a type conversion that involves copying or transforming the data: `ToArray`, `ToString`. Then again, `(Orientation)value` is much more straightforward.

---

> ```
> public enum SquareType
> {
>     Foggy,
>     Water,
>     Undamaged,
>     Damaged,
>     Sunk
> }
> ```

The terminology isn't completely unambiguous: the enums could use a `<summary>` xml-doc comment to enhance IntelliSense when using them.

```
/// <summary>The state of a single grid position.</summary>
public enum SquareType
{
    /// <summary>Unknown state.</summary>
    Foggy,
    /// <summary>Grid position was previously attacked, and revealed water.</summary>
    Water,
    /// <summary>Grid position contains a ship.</summary>
    Undamaged,
    /// <summary>Grid position was previously attacked, and revealed a ship.</summary>
    Damaged,
    /// <summary>Grid position was previously attacked, and the ship was sunken.</summary>
    Sunk
}
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding what each value stands for, I think the enum is mixing concerns a bit: `Sunk` isn't a grid position state, it's a *ship* state: as far as the game grid is concerned, whether the ship there is sunken or just hit makes no difference: there's a red pin at that position. I believe more descriptive names could be used, that would make the xml-doc less necessary:

```
public enum GridState
{
    Unknown,
    ShipPosition,
    PreviousMiss,
    PreviousHit,
}
```

The `Orientation` enum is fine, but IMO could be simplified to `Horizontal` and `Vertical` - whether it's pointing left or pointing right doesn't make any difference, unless your UI wants to make that difference... but then again, game-wise, it changes nothing and I'd concentrate on getting a solid model first, and *then* augment it with bells & whistles like game state serialization and 4-directional ships.

---

#### GridSquare

IMO the class is superfluous, and knows way too many things about its world: a grid cell should be just that: a *grid cell*, i.e. a `SquareType` (/`GridState`) value. It's not its job to know or care about what specific ship might occupy that space, even less to know that ships are indexed, and that a specific index corresponds to a particular ship. A `GridSquare` class would be something I'd write at the UI layer, with information such as `PixelSize`, `BorderColor`, some `Click`, `DoubleClick`, and `Hover` handlers: it has nothing to do in the model!

#### Grid

I find the grid class rather anemic, ..and IMO the grid size should be constant: Battleship is played on a 10x10 grid in every variant that involves 5 ships with sizes 5-4-3-3-2. If you want a parameterized grid size, then you'll want configurable fleet setups, ...but at this point it's scope-creep: keep it stupid simple (KISS).

Your grid is essentially a 2D array of grid state values: it might as well *be* a 2D array of grid state values.

#### Ship

> ```
> public class Ship
> {
>     public ShipType ShipType { get; set; }
>     public Orientation Orientation { get; set; }
>     public int Health { get; set; }
> ```

Why would a ship's `ShipType` or `Orientation` need to ever change after it's created? These should be get-only, immutable values assigned in the constructor. And if `Health` is meant to be assigned through `Hit` and `Repair` methods, then the setter shouldn't be `public`.

```
public Ship(ShipType shipType, Orientation orientation)
{
    ShipType = shipType;
    Orientation = orientation;
}

public ShipType ShipType { get; }
public Orientation Orientation { get; }
public int Health { get; private set; }
```

I like the simplicity of modeling ship damage as "hit points", however the "health" alone doesn't tell us anything about the state of the ship (i.e. *where* is it hit?), which means our API needs to get the *state of the ship*... from *not-the-ship*.

```
private bool[] _state;
```

With an internal array of `bool` values, we can track the ship's health *and* know where it's hit, *in one place*. Then the `Health` can be get-only as well:

```
public int Health => _state.Count(e => e); // counts the 'true' elements in _state
```

#### Player

Again, mutability is problematic here; `Grid` and `Ships` should have private setters, if at all:

```
    public Grid Grid { get; set; }
    public List<Ship> Ships { get; set; }
```

I agree with a player owning a grid, but as I said above I would have made the grid own the ships.

Comment: I wasn't too sure about how powerful the `XmlSerialization` stuff is, and left some fields that would be privately set completely public so nothing would go wrong. Every single Microsoft example uses `public` instance variables.

Comment: So I wonder, if you add the `_state` array to `Ship` to store information about which part is hit, do you still save the state in `Grid`? The undamaged/damaged/sunk distinction is made in gridstate. If you're removing the ship index information from the grid, you would have to move the `hit` methods  and their logic to the ships.

Comment: @JAD IMO a ship needs to know its position, direction, and hit-state; the grid needs to know where the ships are, independently of ship state - so you can have an unknown grid state while having an enemy ship at that position. Now I might have a design bias there, for I recently made a battleship game (see github link in comments under the OP), but yes IMO ship and grid state need to be distinct.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I agree with you here, but does the grid need to know whether that ship was damaged or not? Also, if I understand correctly, you say the grid should own the ships, so then the grid also should own the logic for handling hits right?

Comment: @Mr.Vix XML serialization does require public getters and setters. Hence I'd have a dedicated model for serialization - wouldn't let a persistence concern drive the design... like I said I'd make a solid working model first, then think of adding features like game state serialization.

Comment: @JAD the grid can query the ship state as needed, and yes it would be responsible for applying a hit on a ship.